# How to integrate IBM Integration bus with IBM Process designer

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, ibm-bpm

I am new to IBM Integration bus and I would really appreciate if anybody tell me how to connect IIB with the PD (IBM BPM). I tried to get some reference materials for the same but the description in the material is for Message broker fix pack 1 and its different from what we have now in IIB 9.0.0 & 10.0.0

Comment: Which version of IBM BPM, 8, 8.5? Express, Standard, Advanced?

Answer (score 0):

IBM BPM can expose some Web Sercives if you build then within a Process Aplication. By the book the IBM BPM come with a REST API to interact to product itself.

Consider this charecteristcs the way to integrate with then is using HTTP Request ou SOAP Request in the IBM Integration Bus Flow.

Answer (score 0):

there are certain ways to communicate IIB with IBM BPM.
1 through web services (SOAP and REST).
2 UCA(Under Cover agent)
3 Database
but preferred way would be UCA and Web Services